# Deploying Kong with Postgres db in Azure App service

Tags: docker-compose, azure-web-app-service, kong

I want to deploy Kong with DB mode on the Azure App Service using the docker-compose file.

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:
https://github.com/saurabhmasc/kong-compose/blob/main/docker-compose.yml

This file is running properly in Doker Desktop.
But when I tried to run it in Azure app services it was not running.

Please gives us suggestions.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: ` it was not running.` is quite dried. Any error logs ?

Comment: Make sure your IP address is allowed under "Connection Security" before connecting to your new database.

Comment: Please refer [Running Kong on Azure Container Instances](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/tomkerkhove/microsoft_azure_container_instances/)